# How to prevent autofill script-attack on Angular form (spam)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I user Angular: 1.4.8

On my site I have a small form and I want to prevent the form to be autofilled by a script and then submited.

I have tried to alter the value by:

```
document.getElementByID('id').value = "newValue"
```

But then when I submit my from and check on the viewValue/modelValue of the field, they are unchanged, same for my vm.id.

Does AngularJS have som builtin support to prevent spam by autofill/script-attack? Or is it just me who dont know how to test it?

Comment: If you do this you may try a $scope.$apply() to see if the ngModel update :). I don't know anything about aufill attack

Comment: That only works if I update the value I have in my scope, in my case $scope.vm.id.. Byt if the value is changed by document.getElementById('id') nothing happens.    Thanks anyway

Comment: what about angular.element('"#id").scope().$apply() ?

Comment: As far as I can see I still have the same result..